# Comparing variances for estimators

Tags: statistics, expectation, estimation, variance, parameter-estimation

Let $\tilde \beta$ and $\hat \beta$ be two different estimators of a parameter $\beta$ with $E(\tilde \beta)=\beta$ and $E(\hat \beta)=\beta$.
I want to determine which estimator is superior. Since both are unbiased, I look to their variances:

$Var(\tilde \beta)=\frac{\sigma ^2 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{X_{i}^2}}{n^2}$

$Var(\hat \beta)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}^2}$

I tried $Var(\hat \beta)-Var(\tilde \beta)$ as well as $\frac{Var(\hat \beta)}{Var(\tilde \beta)}$ but can't seem to make anything out of them. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\text{E}[\frac{1}{X^2}]$

$\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\frac{1}{\text{E}[X^2]}$

Applying Jensen's inequality, $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}) \le \text{Var}(\tilde{\beta})$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you elaborate on how you arrived to those two results for the variances? Is it by using the definition of expectation for discrete random variables?

Comment: Yes. I guess I actually took some liberties in the interpretation of your question, assuming that the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed (iid).

Comment: Yep, I did mix it up. Corrected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to: if $x_i$ are positive numbers, which is bigger, $\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}$, or $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$? Well, we know that $f(x)=1/x$ is convex for $x>0$ (its second derivative is $2/x^3>0$), so it follows that $\frac{1}{\sum_i c_i x_i} \leq \sum_i c_i \frac{1}{x_i}$ whenever $c_i$ are nonnegative numbers summing to $1$ and $x_i$ are positive numbers. Take $c_i=\frac{1}{n}$ and see what you conclude.

This can be regarded as a case of Jensen's inequality, where we are comparing $E[f(X)]$ and $f(E[X])$ where $f(x)=1/x$ and $X$ is a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the set $\{ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $p^{\rm th}$ power mean $$M_p(\boldsymbol x) = \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p\right)^{1/p}$$ obeys the property $$p < q \implies M_p(\boldsymbol x) \le M_q(\boldsymbol x).$$  Thus, for $p = -1 < 1 = q$, we have $$M_{-1}(\boldsymbol x^2) \le M_1(\boldsymbol x^2),$$ or $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i^2} \ge \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{-1}.$$  Multiplying both sides by $\sigma^2/n$ gives $$\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i^2} \ge \sigma^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{-1},$$ which can also be seen by considering Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, doesn't Stanley's answer arrive to the opposite result?

Comment: @Sadem The direction of the inequality as stated in my response, is correct.  Note that taking the reciprocal of both sides of an inequality results in a change in the direction of that inequality.